# Skip row that logical value is false

Tags: excel, function

I tried using if else but I can't figure out how to do it right.

I have set of columns that has a name with ratings. I want to get the names of person with ratings 3 and below WITHOUT blank cells.

Thank you in advance[Cell in Red box should be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaQTU.png)

Answer (score 0):

`FILTER()` is perfect for you. Try-

```
=FILTER(B3:B9,A3:A9<=3)
```

[image]

Comment: love the solution @harun24hr thanks. simple and effective